Adding a ground loop on the edge of the PCB
I saw on some PCB, the they have added a ground loop on the edge of a PCB, I wonder what would be the benefits of this?


Is this an actual ground loop in the EMI/routing sense, or just exposed edges of a continuous ground plane?

@ I wanted to ask mainly about the ground plane around the edge not the  holes.

@ nanofarad yes, it is a ground loop in the EMI/routing sense

Is one of the other layers of this board a ground plane?

@ The Photon Yes, it is, it is an 14 layer GND, there several internal GND planes.

Two likely possibilities:

This "loop" is connected to one or more internal ground plane layers of the board. In that case it is not a loop at all, but merely the top of a low wall or fence extending from the ground plane(s). Extending the ground plane to the top layer basically forces all other nets on the top layer to be pushed away from the board edge. This allows a greater portion of the field lines from those nets to terminate on the ground structure rather than radiate into space.

This "loop" is not connected to an internal ground layer. In this case it is likely meant to be connected to the enclosure or chassis ground. Then at some point the chassis ground will be weakly coupled (for example through a megohm resistor) to the signal ground of the system, ensuring the two grounds do not drift too far apart in potential. A strong coupling between them is not desirable because it would allow signal currents to flow out to the chassis where they might cause radiation.



From my experience, this is a thermal interface to a frame or chassis. To avoid an actual ground loop this copper can be net tied to ground at a single point.

And to avoid it being a loop, it might be left open at some point instead of being a loop.

A closed loop is good, since it resists magnetic flux that might otherwise thread the board and cause EMI in more sensitive loops.
